# how to validate and remove white spaces in textfield text in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

```
guard let text = txtField.text, !text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty else{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New alert!", message:"Please Enter Email Id", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

If I am using above code I am only removing leading spaces in textfield. I want to remove spaces contained in textfield text.

Answer (score -1):

use this following extension string

```
  extension String
    {

        func isNumber() -> Bool{
            let numberCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
            return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacter(from:numberCharacters) == nil
        }
        struct NumberFormat
        {
            static let instance = NumberFormatter()
        }
        var integerValue:Int?
        {
            if self.isEmpty
            {
                return 0
            }
            else
            {
                return (NumberFormat.instance.number(from: self)?.intValue) ?? 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with removing whitespaces from a string?